# Error during running thunderbird in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, thunderbird

I have run thunderbird in Centos from cli. I got this

```
$ thunderbird 
/usr/lib64/thunderbird/thunderbird: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/thunderbird/libxul.so: undefined symbol: gdk_window_get_visual
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How did you install thunderbird? Did you recently upgrade system packages incompletely? Do you still have any pending updates to apply?

Comment: thanks update solved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes if gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64 package is not installed.
Run `yum install gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64`
That solve the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

that worked for me ----> yum install gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64

Comment: please add a description what your call does